# Kindly break this code

Tags: cipher

axca apax a xadxaght dzaazy, whala a paxdazad, waak axd waazy,
avaz xaxy a qaaaxt axd cazaaaz valaxa af fazgattax laza—
Whala a xaddad, xaazly xappaxg, zaddaxly thaza caxa a tappaxg,
Az af zaxa axa gaxtly zappaxg, zappaxg at xy chaxbaz daaz.
"'Taz zaxa vazataz," a xattazad, "tappaxg at xy chaxbaz daaz—
axly thaz axd xathaxg xaza."

Ah, daztaxctly a zaxaxbaz at waz ax tha blaak Dacaxbaz;
Axd aach zapazata dyaxg axbaz wzaaght atz ghazt apax tha flaaz.
aagazly a wazhad tha xazzaw;—vaaxly a had zaaght ta bazzaw
Fzax xy baakz zazcaaza af zazzaw—zazzaw faz tha lazt Laxaza—
Faz tha zaza axd zadaaxt xaadax whax tha axgalz xaxa Laxaza—
xaxalazz haza faz avazxaza.

Axd tha zalkax, zad, axcaztaax zaztlaxg af aach pazpla caztaax
Thzallad xa—fallad xa wath faxtaztac tazzazz xavaz falt bafaza;
za that xaw, ta ztall tha baataxg af xy haazt, a ztaad zapaataxg
"'Taz zaxa vazataz axtzaataxg axtzaxca at xy chaxbaz daaz—
zaxa lata vazataz axtzaataxg axtzaxca at xy chaxbaz daaz;—
Thaz at az axd xathaxg xaza."

Pzazaxtly xy zaal gzaw ztzaxgaz; hazatataxg thax xa laxgaz,
"zaz," zaad a, "az xadax, tzaly yaaz fazgavaxazz a axplaza;
Bat tha fact az a waz xappaxg, axd za gaxtly yaa caxa zappaxg,
Axd za faaxtly yaa caxa tappaxg, tappaxg at xy chaxbaz daaz,
That a zcazca waz zaza a haazd yaa"—haza a apaxad wada tha daaz;—
Dazkxazz thaza axd xathaxg xaza.

Daap axta that dazkxazz paazaxg, laxg a ztaad thaza waxdazaxg, faazaxg,
Daabtaxg, dzaaxaxg dzaaxz xa xaztal avaz dazad ta dzaax bafaza;
Bat tha zalaxca waz axbzakax, axd tha ztallxazz gava xa takax,
Axd tha axly wazd thaza zpakax waz tha whazpazad wazd, "Laxaza?"
Thaz a whazpazad, axd ax acha xazxazad back tha wazd, "Laxaza!"—
xazaly thaz axd xathaxg xaza.

Back axta tha chaxbaz tazxaxg, all xy zaal wathax xa bazxaxg,
zaax agaax a haazd a tappaxg zaxawhat laadaz thax bafaza.
"zazaly," zaad a, "zazaly that az zaxathaxg at xy waxdaw lattaca;
Lat xa zaa, thax, what thazaat az, axd thaz xyztazy axplaza—
Lat xy haazt ba ztall a xaxaxt axd thaz xyztazy axplaza;—
'Taz tha waxd axd xathaxg xaza!"

apax haza a flaxg tha zhattaz, whax, wath xaxy a flazt axd flattaz,
ax thaza ztappad a ztataly zavax af tha zaaxtly dayz af yaza;
xat tha laazt abaazaxca xada ha; xat a xaxata ztappad az ztayad ha;
Bat, wath xaax af lazd az lady, pazchad abava xy chaxbaz daaz—
Pazchad apax a bazt af Pallaz jazt abava xy chaxbaz daaz—
Pazchad, axd zat, axd xathaxg xaza.

Thax thaz abaxy bazd bagaalaxg xy zad faxcy axta zxalaxg,
By tha gzava axd ztazx dacazax af tha caaxtaxaxca at waza,
"Thaagh thy czazt ba zhazx axd zhavax, thaa," a zaad, "azt zaza xa czavax,
Ghaztly gzax axd axcaaxt zavax waxdazaxg fzax tha xaghtly zhaza—
Tall xa what thy lazdly xaxa az ax tha xaght'z Plataxaax zhaza!"
Qaath tha zavax "xavazxaza."

xach a xazvallad thaz axgaaxly fawl ta haaz dazcaazza za plaaxly,
Thaagh atz axzwaz lattla xaaxaxg—lattla zalavaxcy baza;
Faz wa caxxat halp agzaaaxg that xa lavaxg haxax baaxg
avaz yat waz blazzad wath zaaaxg bazd abava haz chaxbaz daaz—
Bazd az baazt apax tha zcalptazad bazt abava haz chaxbaz daaz,
Wath zach xaxa az "xavazxaza."

Bat tha zavax, zattaxg laxaly ax tha placad bazt, zpaka axly
That axa wazd, az af haz zaal ax that axa wazd ha dad aatpaaz.
xathaxg fazthaz thax ha attazad—xat a faathaz thax ha flattazad—
Tall a zcazcaly xaza thax xattazad "athaz fzaaxdz hava flawx bafaza—
ax tha xazzaw ha wall laava xa, az xy Hapaz hava flawx bafaza."
Thax tha bazd zaad "xavazxaza."

ztaztlad at tha ztallxazz bzakax by zaply za aptly zpakax,
"Daabtlazz," zaad a, "what at attazz az atz axly ztack axd ztaza
Caaght fzax zaxa axhappy xaztaz whax axxazcafal Dazaztaz
Fallawad fazt axd fallawad faztaz tall haz zaxgz axa bazdax baza—
Tall tha dazgaz af haz Hapa that xalaxchaly bazdax baza
af 'xavaz—xavazxaza'."

Bat tha zavax ztall bagaalaxg xy zad faxcy axta zxalaxg,
ztzaaght a whaalad a cazhaaxad zaat ax fzaxt af bazd, axd bazt axd daaz;
Thax, apax tha valvat zaxkaxg, a bataak xyzalf ta laxkaxg
Faxcy axta faxcy, thaxkaxg what thaz axaxaaz bazd af yaza—
What thaz gzax, axgaaxly, ghaztly, gaaxt, axd axaxaaz bazd af yaza
xaaxt ax czaakaxg "xavazxaza."

Thaz a zat axgagad ax gaazzaxg, bat xa zyllabla axpzazzaxg
Ta tha fawl whaza faazy ayaz xaw bazxad axta xy bazax'z caza;
Thaz axd xaza a zat davaxaxg, wath xy haad at aaza zaclaxaxg
ax tha cazhaax'z valvat laxaxg that tha laxp-laght glaatad a'az,
Bat whaza valvat-vaalat laxaxg wath tha laxp-laght glaataxg a'az,
zha zhall pzazz, ah, xavazxaza!

Thax, xathaaght, tha aaz gzaw daxzaz, pazfaxad fzax ax axzaax caxzaz
zwaxg by zazaphax whaza faat-fallz taxklad ax tha taftad flaaz.
"Wzatch," a czaad, "thy Gad hath laxt thaa—by thaza axgalz ha hath zaxt thaa
zazpata—zazpata axd xapaxtha, fzax thy xaxazaaz af Laxaza;
Qaaff, ah qaaff thaz kaxd xapaxtha axd fazgat thaz lazt Laxaza!"
Qaath tha zavax "xavazxaza."

"Pzaphat!" zaad a, "thaxg af aval!—pzaphat ztall, af bazd az daval!—
Whathaz Taxptaz zaxt, az whathaz taxpazt tazzad thaa haza azhaza,
Dazalata yat all axdaaxtad, ax thaz dazazt laxd axchaxtad—
ax thaz haxa by Hazzaz haaxtad—tall xa tzaly, a axplaza—
az thaza—az thaza balx ax Galaad?—tall xa—tall xa, a axplaza!"
Qaath tha zavax "xavazxaza."

"Pzaphat!" zaad a, "thaxg af aval!—pzaphat ztall, af bazd az daval!
By that Haavax that baxdz abava az—by that Gad wa bath adaza—
Tall thaz zaal wath zazzaw ladax af, wathax tha daztaxt Aadaxx,
at zhall clazp a zaaxtad xaadax whax tha axgalz xaxa Laxaza—
Clazp a zaza axd zadaaxt xaadax whax tha axgalz xaxa Laxaza."
Qaath tha zavax "xavazxaza."

"Ba that wazd aaz zagx af paztaxg, bazd az faaxd!" a zhzaakad, apztaztaxg—
"Gat thaa back axta tha taxpazt axd tha xaght'z Plataxaax zhaza!
Laava xa black plaxa az a takax af that laa thy zaal hath zpakax!
Laava xy laxalaxazz axbzakax!—qaat tha bazt abava xy daaz!
Taka thy baak fzax aat xy haazt, axd taka thy fazx fzax aff xy daaz!"
Qaath tha zavax "xavazxaza."

Axd tha zavax, xavaz flattaxg, ztall az zattaxg, ztall az zattaxg
ax tha pallad bazt af Pallaz jazt abava xy chaxbaz daaz;
Axd haz ayaz hava all tha zaaxaxg af a daxax'z that az dzaaxaxg,
Axd tha laxp-laght a'az hax ztzaaxaxg thzawz haz zhadaw ax tha flaaz;
Axd xy zaal fzax aat that zhadaw that laaz flaataxg ax tha flaaz
zhall ba laftad—xavazxaza!

Comment: Too, WAY too long

Comment: please refer to [this](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do) meta post.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not clear, and it is too long.

Comment: ba yaxyxy ayx bab zallbl bax alal...yeah...something like that...

Answer (score 4):

This is just

> the poem *The Raven*, by Edgar Allan Poe, with the following replacements:
>
>  `E → A`
>  `I → A`
>  `M → X`
>  `N → X`
>  `O → A`
>  `R → Z`
>  `S → Z`
>  `U → A`

(It's not even really a code, because it's nowhere near reversible.)